# Managing a thread over multiple requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a rails (4.1.8) application that I am using with a mongodb instance and am running into an issue with trying to use threads.  I am trying to use a thread to prune the database in the background, but would like to be able to start/stop/monitor this thread from the rails application.  Currently, the starting/stopping/monitoring all works, but the thread appears to be getting killed when it should not be.

So my question is are there any persistent parts of a rails application?

I had thought I might have some luck with config/application.rb but it appears that my understanding of how that works is incorrect.

Here is the class that I am using to do the monitoring

```
class RentalAccountAutoRelease
  def self.instance(rental_account_service)
    @monitor ||= RentalAccountAutoRelease.new(rental_account_service)
  end

  def initialize(rental_account_service)
    @rental_account_service = rental_account_service
  end

  def monitor
    @monitor ||= Thread.new do
      loop do
        #prune database
        sleep 60
      end
    end
  end

  def status
    if @monitor
      if @monitor.alive?
        return {:status => 'on'}
      else
        return {:status => 'off'}
      end
    else
      {:status=>'off'}
    end
  end

  def stop
    if @monitor
      Thread.kill(@monitor)
      @monitor = nil
    end
  end
end
```

I am using this in the config/application.rb

```
module Leo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    def self.apollo_rental_account_service
    config = DBConfig.new
    @apollo_rental_account_service ||= RentalAccountService.new(config.apollo["development"]["address"],
                                                         config.apollo["development"]["port"],
                                                         config.apollo["development"]["rental_accounts"]["db_name"],
                                                         config.apollo["development"]["rental_accounts"]["collection_name"])
    end

    def self.rate_view_rental_account_service
      config = DBConfig.new
      @rate_view_rental_account_service ||= RentalAccountService.new(config.rate_view["development"]["address"],
                                                           config.rate_view["development"]["port"],
                                                           config.rate_view["development"]["rental_accounts"]["db_name"],
                                                           config.rate_view["development"]["rental_accounts"]["collection_name"])
    end

    def self.siebel_rental_account_service
      config = DBConfig.new
      @siebel_rental_account_service ||= RentalAccountService.new(config.siebel["development"]["address"],
                                                           config.siebel["development"]["port"],
                                                           config.siebel["development"]["rental_accounts"]["db_name"],
                                                           config.siebel["development"]["rental_accounts"]["collection_name"])
    end

    def self.auto_release
      @auto_release = RentalAccountAutoRelease.instance([Leo::Application.apollo_rental_account_service,
                                                         Leo::Application.rate_view_rental_account_service,
                                                         Leo::Application.siebel_rental_account_service])
    end

  end
end
```

Here is how I am using it from the controller

```
class AutoReleaseController < ApplicationController

  def initialize
    begin
      @auto_release = Leo::Application.auto_release
    rescue => e
      puts e
      puts e.backtrace
    ensure
      super
    end
  end


  def status
    render json: JSON.generate(@auto_release.status)
  end

  def start
    @auto_release.monitor
    render json: JSON.generate({:status => 'ok'})
  end

  def stop
    @auto_release.stop
    render json: JSON.generate({:status=>'ok'})
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use threads for background jobs, because in production environment, a Rails application often spawns multiple **processes** in order to achieve concurrency (Rails applications often run in single-threaded mode). So in your case, there will be one background job per process.

The preferred way of implementing a background job is to separate that job from the processes of Rails application. For example, you can write a long-term **rake task** run in the background which traps UNIX signals or listens to socket requests on some specific port. Your Rails application just send signals or requests to that task to monitor and control it.

Comment: I kind of thought that was happening (multiple processes were being spawned) but I am still very new to rails and wasn't sure. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: A follow up question to your answer here @Aetherus. If I place a script in the initializers directory, will that code be run every time a new process is spawned or just when the rails app is first booted up?